# Callback and asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, callback

I have a following situation. I have a gridview and I need to dynamically add rows to it. All works fine and dandy. However, lately, I have been curious about making this process faster and more usable. I found a Callback feature in asp.net 2.0.

It seems to make sense for a case when the gridview is used ti display something. Adding a row programmatically however, requires to add a row to DataTable (that's gridview bound to). Since DataTable resides on the server, from what I understand it doesn't make sense here to use Callback....

[this](http://csharpfeeds.com/post/4287/Asynchronous_GridView_in_5_simple_steps.aspx) is a nice tutorial that outlines main things.

in step 5:

"To finish the asynchronous loading we have to implement the two methods that are defined by the ICallbackEventHandler interface we implemented in step 3. One of the methods binds a DataTable to the GridView and renders the control."

from that I gather that there is no way to make dynamically adding rows to gridview w/o postbacks....any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct -- you can't dynamically add rows to a GridView without a postback.  You can add rows to the html  on the client side, but they won't be recognized after the next postback.

I generally do what you're describing with just a plain HTML table on the client side using jQuery, and making jQuery ajax calls where it's appropriate.